# The usage of dative case

Tags: дательный-падеж

I had a long break (~6 months) from learning Russian and now I'm a little confused.

Does

> {personal_pronoun}_dative + (не) + infinitve + что, for example
>
> Мне (не) прочитать эту книгу

mean

> I must (mustn't) read this book

or

> I (don't) want to read this book

or something else?

/edit: the Russian examples I know about include dative + infinitive with out "не", for instance

> Что же мне делать, один против всех

(Эпидемия - Рождённый для битвы)

> мне ещё ребёнка забирать:

[source](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Comment: Infinitive + dative without не seems to be possible: *мне ещё ребёнка забирать*: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2

Comment: Did you mean: clause `I/YOU_dat + INF`? To us, it is everyday Russian since earliest childhood, and represent the most frequent phrase in spoken discourse. **[Proof](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=SPRO%2Cdat%2C%281p%7C2p%29&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=V%2Cinf&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=).**

Comment: I mean {personal_pronoun}_dat + INF

Comment: [even more](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=SPRO%2Cdat%2Canim&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=V%2Cinf&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=)

Answer (score 4):

*Мне прочитать эту книгу* and *Мне **не** прочитать эту книгу* are quite different.

The former only makes sense as a question: `Мне прочитать эту книгу?` "Am I to read this book?" (Implying a rather weak degree of obligation/prescription, not "must".)

The latter, negative one is a somewhat high-sounding "Never will I read this book!" (Implying intervening circumstances, *not* the speaker's defiance.) It's a little difficult to imagine the circumstances in which one would use this construction to talk about not getting to read a book. An alternative, and rarer, meaning could be "I don't have what it takes to read this book" (i.e. it's too difficult or cryptic).

Comment: (1) There is no dot after the last wo, in the OP, so it is not a sentence;(2) there had been a variation as shown by the braces, which make no sense in ordinary texts, but are found widely as available cases from textbooks. Thus, (3) it is `phrases | сочетания слов`. Authors are welcomed to write case studies, whether it is a word or phrase (group of words with some unity) or finished sentences.It goes without saying that if (a) given phrase is to be considered as sentences; (b) `are quite different` is false in grammatical terms; then claims in your answer are probably false to some degree.

Comment: @Avtokod With all due respect, the only coherent statement I've managed to make out in your comment — that their being "quite different" is false "in grammatical terms" — is irrelevant because this is rather obviously a question about meaning and usage.

Comment: If you do not deny that it is not a sentence, sorry, then your claim **The former only makes sense as a question: Мне прочитать эту книгу?** is a false one. [Proof](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%83%22&num=30&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=fTxqVfC6NIr8UOzJgZAJ&ved=0CA0Q_AUoAA&biw=1279&bih=679).

Comment: @Avtokod Presumably, if the question is to make any sense, it is at least a complete clause. As opposed to something like *Мне прочитать эту книгу не удавалось уже года полтора.*

Comment: Положим, я англичанин/испанец/китаец/..., знаю логику и математику, и изучаю русский язык. Вот мне пишут такое объяснение. Я спрашиваю себя, почему русские считают, что в **`сочетание слов`** можно добавить вопросительный знак в конец, а в начало добавить слово `хочется` нельзя? А затем \*для проверки\*, что случай этот, с вопросительным знаком, якобы единственный, добавлять любые слова в конец — опять можно. Что там у русских с логикой? )) Это же произвольные суждения. Надо исправлять ответ.

Comment: @Avtokod (Я готов к административным мерам за этот мой комментарий.) Кончайте бредить, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, "мне не прочитать эту книгу" means "I can't read (finish reading) this book". For example, because it is difficult or long etc. You cannot finish it.

"Мне прочитать эту книгу" sounds wrong and nobody will ever say or understand this. It has no meaning.

Comment: "Мне прочитать эту книгу?" as a question sounds good and clear

Comment: Комната, полная ребятишек, гудела как улей. Наконец, вошла нянечка. Только двое ребятишек заметили, что она держит в руках книгу. "Кому почитать книгу?" — спросила няня, впрочем, не ожидая интереса от детворы. **"Мне прочитать эту книгу."** — негромко сказал один из мальчишек, глядя, как зачарованный, на обложку книги. Он даже немного повернул голову, чтобы разгадать те непонятные знаки, на которые смотрят взрослые, а потом плавно и длинно разговаривают.

Comment: @Avtokod That's a childish talk ;-) Adult people can say this only as a joke: "А кому дать?" - "А мне дать!"  etc.

Comment: @user4419802 , And what about **[this](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_created&out=normal&dpp=30&spd=10&seed=6305&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=SPRO%2Cdat%2C%281p+%7C+2p%29&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=first&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=V%2Cinf&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=)**?

Comment: @Avtokod The problem is that the sentence "Мне прочитать книгу" has a little meaning. It's possible to use it but you have hard times inventing the setting for it first. Say, "Гореть ему в аду, а мне прочитать эту книгу" ^-) So it's not really wrong but very troublesome to use. Concerning your examples, as you see, the most part of them are questions or very archaic language.

Comment: Yes, but the sentence was a simple example. I meant, as in another comment, {personal_pronoun}_dative + infinitive with/without не

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрим минимально законченный синтаксический образец, включающий предложенную фразу, **где есть и подлежащее, и сказуемое**.

```
  Мне  прочитать   эту книгу — хорошо.
  Мне не прочитать эту книгу — плохо.
```

Сказуемое здесь выражено наречием, отвечающим на вопрос "каково?". Подлежащее — глагол в инфинитиве.

Малая грамматическая обусловленность в предложенном примере оставляет **неопределенности**, которые и вызывают трудности у изучающего русский язык.

**а)** Отсутствующее сказуемое (один из двух главных членов предложения заключающий в себе высказывание, делающий выражение мысли законченным - [сл.Ушакова]) оставляет неопределенность в отношении представленного действия `прочитать` и его предикативным признаком: *это хорошо? плохо? весело? вовремя? ...*

**б)** Неопределенность во времени:

```
  Прочитать — хорошо.            Настоящее
  Прочитать было хорошо.         Прошедшее
  Прочитать будет хорошо.        Будущее
```

**в)** Неопределенность в наклонении (как иллюстрация):

```
  Прочитать было бы хорошо.                        Сослагательное

  Если бы прочитать было хорошо ... /                
     (было бы прочитать хорошо, если ...)          Условное

  Было бы прочитать хорошо!                        Желательное
```

---

---

**(1)** There is no dot after the last word, in the OP, so it is not a sentence; **(2)** there had been a variation as shown by the braces, which make no sense in ordinary texts, but are found widely as available cases from textbooks. Thus, **(3)** it is `phrases | сочетания слов`.

We shall consider an auxiliary sentence. For that **we have to finish the sentence.**

```
  Мне  прочитать  эту книгу —  хорошо.
      └── subj ─┘            └─ praed ─┘
          V_inf                 Adv
          └──── How? Каково? ────┘
```

When we say
`Мне не прочитать эту книгу — плохо.`
we mean,

```
  I will not be able to read this book, it's bad.
  I wouldn't be able to ...
  I couldn't be able to ... 
     + probably
  I'm not going to read this book, it's bad. 
  I was not going to read this book, it's bad.
```

Some other examples:

```
  He won't be able to come in time, it's bad. 
  Ему не приехать вовремя, плохо.
         └─ V_inf + Adv ─┘

  They now appeared; she had made each promise to come early.
  Они появились, она имела от каждого обещание прибыть вовремя.
                                              └─ V_inf + Adv ─┘

  It won't hurt you to stand.
  Тебе постоять не вредно.
       └── V_inf + Adv ──┘

  They never go far.
  Им не уйти далеко.
     └ V_inf + Adv ┘
```

---

### About {personal_PROnoun}_dat + VERB_inf

---

Consider the example below:

```
     Для того чтобы уйти из этого мира, ему нужно было бы изжить карму.
  In order for him to leave this world, he needed to put an end to his karma.
```

If there is talk about the same person, normally (even preferably) is 
to drop the first pronoun. But the second isn't (although the sentence would be
fully literate) to avoid confusion.

```
                  ему   (A): omission of personal pronoun, but 
               └──┬──┘       only PRO_dat does apply here.
                  │
                  │
  Для того чтобы (_) уйти из этого мира, ему нужно было бы изжить карму. 
                  ▲    │                  ▲                 │
                  └────┘                  └─────────────────┘
                     \                           /
                      \                         /
                       \                       /
                         ── PRO_dat + V_inf ──
```

But why **(A)**? How can we deduce without the context that to the verb `уйти` there corresponds a uniquely determined case of a pronoun? We can't, without a context.

I have supposition that `PRO_{case:any} + {VERB:any}_inf` is true for Russian.

Answer (score 0):

*Subject infinitive* structure looks like a prophecy. So it is difficult to imagine a setting where this can be used with self with a verb that is dependent on whether you want it be done.